# using 'brew install avr-libc' command on Mac produces error 'no formulae found in taps'

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, avr

I am running MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.1. I am attempting to install the avr embedded development environment.

The command 'brew tap osx-cross/avr' works correctly however when the command 'brew install avr-libc' is used the following error is produced [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeGjn.png)

This produces a problem as files in c cannot be compiled due to avr-gcc being unavailable.

Any help and advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You're supposed to run `brew install avr-gcc`

Comment: Also while roundabout it's worth keeping in mind that you get an avr toolchain if you install the Arduino setup; though it will be in some odd place you have to find before you can use it independently.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: `brew tap osx-cross/avr && brew install avr-gcc`

Needed to expand brew's options of available software, as well as reference the updated avr-gcc instead of avr-libc.

Answer (score 1):

as @nos said, you need to run `brew install avr-gcc`.

More info here: https://github.com/osx-cross/homebrew-avr#installing-homebrew-avr-formulae